# I'm using a hidden for with a checkbox to send strings to a property, but they are sent even if the checkbox isn't checked

Tags: c#, razor, checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc

so I've been trying to use a checkbox to send a list of values to a string property in my model.
but for some reason, the values are sent, even after i initialized with the bool false and left the checkbox unchecked.

these are my models

```
public class Profesor
{        
    public List<AsignaturaModelo> Asignaturas { get; set; }

    public Profesor()
    {
        Asignaturas = new List<AsignaturaModelo>();
    }

}

public class AsignaturaModelo
{
    public string NombreA { get; set; }


    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    
}
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new Profesor
            {
                Asignaturas = new[]
                {
                    new AsignaturaModelo{NombreA = "Programacion 1", Selected = false},
                    new AsignaturaModelo {NombreA = "Programacion 2", Selected = false}
                }.ToList()
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Profesor modelo)
        {
            try
            {
                
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {                   
                    profesors.Add(modelo);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                return View(modelo);
            }
            return View(modelo);
        }
```

My view

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Asignaturas)
```

and my EditorTemplate

```
@model AsignaturaModelo

    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NombreA)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected, Model.NombreA)
    </div>
```

Not sure what am i doing wrong, also sorry for the variable names. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean in the property`Profesor modelo` of post method,you only want selected item to pass their `NombreA`?If so,here is a demo worked.

View:

```
@model Profesor
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Asignaturas, "EditorTemplate")
    <div>
        <input type="submit"  beforesubmit="" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
    var count = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        var id = "#" + $(this).prop("id").replace("Selected", "NombreA");
        var name = $(this).prop("name").replace("Selected", "NombreA");
        var tempname = name.replace(/[0-9]/, "number").replace(/0-9/ig, "");
        $('input[name="' + name.replace("NombreA", "Selected") + '"][type="hidden"]').attr("name", name.replace("NombreA", "Selected") + "_unselected");
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            var newName = tempname.replace("number", ""+count);
            $(id).attr("name", newName);
            $(this).attr("name", newName.replace("NombreA", "Selected"));
            count++;
        } else {
            $(id).attr("name", name + "_unselected");
        }
    })
    return true;
}
</script>
}
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@model List<AsignaturaModelo>
@for (int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].Selected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].NombreA)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x[i].Selected, Model[i].NombreA)
    </div>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This does fix one side of the problem, thank you for the help. but generates a new problem. since the unselected checkboxes posts all other strings to the model as null, i can't edit the model to add or remove any `Asignatura` from the model `Pofesor`.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to pass selected checkboxes to Action?I have updated my answer to show how to pass only selected checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, this does solve my other problem. Thank you very much! and thank you for the fast answers.